# another problem with connecting to wireless

Tags: wireless, connection

Help! I've just installed 12.10 and cannot connect to my wireless connection. The system keeps asking to log in, keeps checking, but can't seem to connect. I know there are many threads on this topic, but my head is spinning trying to figure things out. Thanks anyone!

Okay, tried the Additional Drivers command, but it didn't find anything. Here is what I get from lspci...

02:02.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless LAN 2100 3B Mini PCI Adapter (rev 04)

(Sorry if it's not formatted correctly--still learning the ropes.)

So seems like Intel network card. Let me see what's out there for download--but any advice you have is much appreciated! Thanks so far!

Comment: Is this a fresh install of 12.10?  Has this wireless connection ever worked before? What kind of computer?  What wireless card (do you know how to find out)? What keeps asking to login (Ubuntu, network manager, some external device)? Do you have a wired connection available?

Comment: Yes, a brand new install onto a Thinkpad T41 that used to have XP. Wired connection does work, but Ubuntu keeps asking to connect to the wireless but cannot. Hasn't worked yet since I installed Ubuntu. Not sure what wireless card I have on it.

Comment: Wireless connection worked when the laptop had XP sp2 then stopped at Sp3. (Long story.) that's why I'm trying Ubuntu.

Comment: Ok, I edited the question a little which will also bump back up in the queue if the edits are approved. I'll also start an answer that may end up containing the solution.

Comment: Remember that once you get a solution that works you should "accept" the answer which will help others who have the same problem.

Comment: Boy it really seems like that card should work.  Forgive the question but are you positive the settings are correct (type of encryption, password, etc)?

Comment: It is strange. Encryption and password are what they should be. BSSID is blank, IPv4 and IPv6 are set to automatic. The network card should work--it did when I had XP SP2 on the machine, and it keeps trying to connect (and my iPad connects, to the modem/router is working).

Comment: I get this for ipconfig:     lo        no wireless extensions.

eth1      unassociated  ESSID:"HOME-5AF2"  Nickname:"ipw2100"
          Mode:Managed  Channel=0  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Bit Rate:0 kb/s   Tx-Power:16 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

irda0     no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

Comment: I wonder if it would make a difference if you tried 13.10 using a live usb/cd.  If you were using 12.04 as a LTS I could see sticking with 12.10, but once I go off LTS I generally stick with the latest.  Can't hurt to try it in Live environment anyway.  I also came across a helpful step by step link that you may want to look at which is posted in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal window by either shortcut

> CTRL-ALT-t

or using the dash and typing terminal.  Once the termnal is open use the command

> lspci | grep -i network

which should give you a line of text listing your network card (I'll bet it will have "Broadcom" in the answer.  Once you have that line of text edit your own question and paste that output on it's own line.

I don't have access to a 12.10 box but many wireless problems are solved by using the proprietary drivers.  A good step by step explanation of how to do it can be found at
 http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/find-additional-drivers-in-ubuntu-12-10/
Once you try that if it still doesn't connect edit the question with that fact.

For a more technical walkthrough of some possible steps something like
http://wiki.freegeek.org/index.php/Wireless_Tips
may be helpful